# Reselect Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: redux, react-redux, reselect

I am using reselect and react redux. I am trying to make a selector for a basic modal implementation.

my selector is

```
const selectModal = (state) => state.get('modal');
```

which throws the error of

```
Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

edit: It has been requested I show how I call select modal, though it should make no difference.

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  isVisible: selectModalIsVisible(),
});
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  hideModal,
  showModal
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Modal);
```

I believe this means the modal state container is not being found

Perhaps I am setting up my reducer or store incorrectly. My reducer is

```
function modalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case HIDE_MODAL:
      return state.set(
        'isVisible', false);
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      return  state.set(
        'isVisible', true);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

which is combined with combine reducers into a glob

```
export default function createReducer(asyncReducers){
  return combineReducers({
    route: routeReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    modal: modalReducer,
    ...asyncReducers
  });
}
```

and then injected into my store

```
function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
  const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history),
  ];
  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  ]
  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    fromJS(initialState),
    compose(...enhancers)
  );

  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  //store.close = () => store.dispatch(END)

  store.runSaga(sagas);
  store.asyncReducers = {};
  return store;
}
var initialState = {}
const store = configureStore(fromJS(initialState), browserHistory);
```

The error within reselect is at lines 73/74 params = dependencies.map

```
var selector = function selector(state, props) {
  for (var _len4 = arguments.length, args = Array(_len4 > 2 ? _len4 - 2 : 0), _key4 = 2; _key4 < _len4; _key4++) {
    args[_key4 - 2] = arguments[_key4];
  }

  var params = dependencies.map(function (dependency) {
    return dependency.apply(undefined, [state, props].concat(args));
  });
  return memoizedResultFunc.apply(undefined, _toConsumableArray(params));
};
```

So what am I doing wrong, do I need to do something with immutableJS differently to access the modal, or is my setup for the app incorrect? Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Please add the code that calls `selectModal`.

Comment: @JimBolla it should make no difference, as the error is called long before that point. I worry showing more will confuse more than anything but I have added it.

Comment: Most selectors are of the form `selector = state => doSomething(state)`, while yours is `selector = () => (state) => doSomething(state)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: see here github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containe‌​rs/…

it would seemt he problem is that state is undefined meaning my store is set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `selectModal` like you're using `selectModalIsVisible`, then your syntax is wrong. I'm pretty sure `createStructuredSelector` does not understand `() => (state) => state.get('modal')`. It would only accept `(state) => state.get('modal')`

Typically, my usages of `createStructuredSelector` will look like either

```
const getThing = (state, props) => state.things[props.thingId];
const getModal = state => state.get('modal');

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  thing: getThing, // notice no parens
  modal: getModal, // notice no parens
})
```

OR if I need selector factories:

```
// just pretend this selector was more complicated and needed memoization
const makeGetThing = () => createSelector(
  state => state.things,
  (state, props) => props.thingId,
  (things, thingId) => things[thingId]);
const getModal = state => state.get('modal');

const makeMapStateToProps = () => createStructuredSelector({
  thing: makeGetThing(), // yes parens
  modal: getModal, // no parens
})
```

Comment: thankyou for your feedback @jim-bolla I saw this syntax in some code example while trying to get it to work. However if I revert to const = (state) => state.get('modal') I get the same result. I wonder if I am not plugging in my selectors into my store properly? Or my store is not properly created.

Comment: here's an example of the () => (state) => pattern 
https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/HomePage/selectors.js

Comment: This is the comment that made click for me in differencing factory function selector from normal selectors. Thanks!